# iMacros: How to get the DATE with EVAL

Tags: date, imacros

can someone to give me an direction on this, please

I need this with EVAL, because .js not supported by Chrome.

I have the `{{!EXTRACT}}` and EVAL `{{Day1}} {{Day2}} {{Day3}} {{Day4}}.. {{Day10}}..{{Day20}}`

I am extracting from the webpage  `DATE` in this format `Oct 10, 2022`

if `{{!EXTRACT}}` value is from the past, let's say `Oct 1, 2022` then {{Day1}} value will be the next day after local machine current date, in this case `Oct 12, 2022` , then {{Day2}} `Oct 13, 2022` , {{Day3}} `Oct 14, 2022`  and continue with how many days I SET to generate

Then

if case `{{!EXTRACT}}` value is from the future, `Oct 23, 2022`, then {{Day1}} value will be the next day `Oct 24, 2022`, then {{Day2}} `Oct 25, 2022` , {{Day3}} `Oct 26, 2022` and continue with how many days I SET

hope my information is clear
really don't know how to approach this
thank you again

I am using (FCI): `iMacros for CR v10.1.1 'PE', CR v105.0.5195.102 (_x64), Win10_x64. ('CR' = 'Chrome' / 'PE' = 'Personal Edition')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just trying to give value to the SO comunity as so many times someone with experience helped me.

I found the solution

```
SET !EXTRACT "Oct 21, 2022"
SET Day1 EVAL("var add = 1; var result = new Date(); var resultText = ''; var extract = new Date('{{!EXTRACT}}').setHours(0,0,0,0); var today = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0); if(today > extract){ result.setDate(new Date(today).getDate() + add); } else {result.setDate(new Date(extract).getDate() + add);} resultText = result.toLocaleString('en-US', {month: 'short'}) + ' ' + result.getDate() + ', ' + result.getFullYear(); resultText;")

SET Day2 EVAL("var add = 2; var result = new Date(); var resultText = ''; var extract = new Date('{{!EXTRACT}}').setHours(0,0,0,0); var today = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0); if(today > extract){ result.setDate(new Date(today).getDate() + add); } else {result.setDate(new Date(extract).getDate() + add);} resultText = result.toLocaleString('en-US', {month: 'short'}) + ' ' + result.getDate() + ', ' + result.getFullYear(); resultText;")

PROMPT {{Day1}}_{{Day2}}_
```